# decrypt file use aes-256-cbc node.js iv undefind

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, electron, node-crypto

my key : `crypto.createHash('sha256').update('mySup3rC00lP4ssWord').digest()`

my iv : `crypto.randomBytes(16)`

I try methods in this page : https://medium.com/@brandonstilson/lets-encrypt-files-with-node-85037bea8c0e

I use aes-256-cbc to decrypt a enc file , and this is my encrypting , file path is my location 
C:\Users\芊吠\AppData\Roaming\vue-electron

```js
function fileRead () {
  const AppendInitVect = require('../utils/appendInitVect') // 修改數據
  const path = app.getPath('userData') // appData的位址
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Key, initVect)
  const appendInitVect = new AppendInitVect(initVect)
  const readStream = fs.createReadStream(path + '\\config.json') // 讀檔
  const gzipStream = zlib.createGzip() // 壓縮檔案
  const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(path + '\\config.json.enc') // 新檔案
  readStream.pipe(gzipStream).pipe(cipher).pipe(appendInitVect).pipe(writeStream) // 壓縮再寫檔
}
```

this is my enc file , look at it is encrpt file!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjSp1.png)

but my problem start ... When I decrypt this enc file , it will get error my iv is undefined , 
 because `readIv.on('data', (chunk) => { console.log('data') initVect = chunk // this is not work!!!!initVect is undefiend })` is not work , so my initVect get undefind, and how can I fix it?

this is my decrypting ...

```js
function unFileRead () {
  const path = app.getPath('userData') // appData的位址
  const readIv = fs.createReadStream(path + '\\config.json.enc', { end: 15 }) // 創建iv讀取的steam
  console.log('decrpt path:', path + '\\config.json.enc')
  let initVect
  readIv.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log('data')
    initVect = chunk // this is not work!!!!initVect is undefiend
  })
  console.log('initVect:', initVect)
  readIv.on('close', () => {
    console.log('hello')
    const unzip = zlib.createUnzip()
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(path + '\\config.json.enc', { start: 16 })
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Key, initVect)
    console.log('decipher:', decipher)
    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(path + '\\config.json.unenc') // 寫檔
    readStream.pipe(decipher).pipe(unzip).pipe(writeStream)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The key to understand here is the difference between synchronous and asynchronous code. `initVect` is initialized to `undefined` synchronously, and is set asynchronously. So, when you're trying to `console.log` the `initVect` outside of the `data` and `close` callbacks, it will still be `undefined` since that line is run synchronously.

If you move your `console.log('initVect:', initVect)` underneath your `console.log('hello')`, you should see it.

Hope that helps.